# Play Store In-App Billing custom price programmatically?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-play-services, android-pay

My application is used to buy journey tickets. The ticket price is different everytime. Can I use In-App Billing to make the user pay a custom price everytime? If so how? i.e. can I set the price which the user has to pay programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **cannot** use Google Play In-App Billing to make the user pay a custom price.

Moreover you cannot use Google Play In-App Billing to sell physical goods and services like journey tickets:

> You can use In-app Billing to sell only digital content. You cannot use In-app Billing to sell physical goods, personal services, or anything that requires physical delivery. Unlike with priced applications, once the user has purchased an in-app product there is no refund window.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html

Comment: Also, I believe that Google allows you to sell such physical goods without going through their own billing service, which would seem to save you their 30 percent cut for in-app billing.  Don't take my word for this, but that's my understanding.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot programmaticaly change the price of a product using Google Play In-App Billing .You could fix the price in the Android developer Console .If you still want to custom price at the runtime you could use PAYPAL for that :

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/mobile-overview

Comment: And your app will be rejected by using PayPal

Answer (score 2):

Your use case perfectly fits the Google Wallet Instant Buy API for Android. Google Wallet Instant Buy API for Android is specifically for physical goods and services and has a simple integration into your Android App. It was launched during Google I/O 2013 and you can get an overview at the following blog post:

http://googlecommerce.blogspot.com/2013/05/fast-and-easy-checkout-for-android-apps.html

Also, please checkout the Google I/O Talk on the same topic

https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/330844794

Since this is still in beta, if you're interested please sign up using the interest form

http://getinstantbuy.withgoogle.com/

Comment: Please keep in mind that Google Instant Buy only supports USD as a currency.