# InAppBilling V3 Android. Donate variable amount

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing

Is this possible in the InAppBilling V3? I want to have a donate button and the user can edit the price he will pay?. Any Suggestion on how to do this?

As you can see on the screen but it will ask for a default price.

[image]

Comment: I'd just create a bunch of "products" with a random interval. Like, $1, $3, $5, $10, $20... and so on. :)

Comment: Please explain for the downflag? to make my question good in the future? or else you are just a troll or just preventing us newbies to improve. Thanks.

Comment: @ninetwozero so do you mean that this is not possible? like the price is variable?

Comment: 3 down vote may be an explanation please? Thanks. I'm a newbie here.

Comment: Have a look at this SO-Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265202/play-store-in-app-billing-custom-price-progammatically it is not perfectly the same situation, but he wants to achieve the same target.

Comment: @user1885518 thanks you very much. I therefore conclude that it is not possible. I think you can answer this question as not possible.

Comment: Please downvote more and no explaination why the downvote. It helped a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into it a bit more, I've noticed that it's currently not possible to achieve. However, I'd recommend that you instead set up a bunch of "in-app products" with various amounts, something like this:

$1, $3, $5, $10, $20, $50... and so on.

Just my two cents. :)

Comment: I think google should update the billing that include the donation. Because I think they will banned you if you use paypal etc.